# How to word wrap in a table while also having different cell widths?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make a `table` with rows of equal widths except for the last column, which is wider, while also getting the text to wrap in the last column.

I got the text to wrap using `table-layout:fixed` and `word-wrap:break-word`, but that seems to override the `width` property I applied to the `td:nth-child(4)` element and it makes all the column widths the same. How can I achieve this word wrapping in the last column while also having the column widths to be different?

```css
table{
 border-collapse:separate;
 color: black;
 padding-left:5px;
 float:left;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border-spacing:4px;
 width:600px;
 table-layout:fixed;
 
}

th{
 font-size:20px;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:0px;
 vertical-align: top;
}

td{
 border: 1px solid white;
 height:198px;
 vertical-align:top; 
}

td:nth-child(4){
 width:350px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>   
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Ranking</th>
      <th>Significance</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>name</td>
     <td>age</td>
     <td>rank</td>
     <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table-layout: fixed` allows you to set fixed column width by setting the widths of the `<th>` or the `<td>` of the first row if there's no `<th>`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-spacing: 4px;
  width: 600px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 83px;
}

th:last-of-type {
  width: 350px
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 198px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Ranking</th>
    <th>Significance</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>age</td>
    <td>rank</td>        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```